# HTML Element set to Relative Position covers Top Navigation bar set to Fixed

Tags: html, css

I have a top nav bar  set to a fixed position, and I have a article element set to window height. When I set the article element to relative, the navbar is no longer shown.

How can I have the article be window height and the nav bar just kinda rest over it.

Here is my code.

```
<article id="navWrap">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#headWrap">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#workWrapper">My Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contactpage">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </article>

        <article id="headWrap" class="head clearIt">
            <header>
                <p class="headpar">Hello I'm</p>
                <h1 class="headText">Sebastian</h1>
                <p class="headinfo">Web Developer | Corona SDK Developer | PHP Junkie</p>
            </header>
        </article>
```

And the CSS

```
#navWrap{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

nav{
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 39px;
    float: right;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
}

/*Used to clear floats*/
.clearIt{
    clear: both;
}

#headWrap{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #2980b9;
   position: relative;
}
```

And the JS to make the article window height

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#headWrap").height($(window).height()); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `top:100px;` to your existing css for `#headWrap` to push it down below `#navWrap`

```
#headWrap{
    top:100px;
}
```

---

Once you do that, you can't see the white text on the white background. So add `background:#eee;` to your existing css for `#navWrap`.

```
#navWrap{
    background:#eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the z-index for the nav element to 2.

And the rest of the elements I set to 1.